# Regex to extract text between <b> and <strong> tag

Tags: python, regex

I need to extract the text between the  and  tag using regex in python.

Example: `Customizable:<strong>Features Windows 10 Pro</strong> and legacy ports <b>including VGA,</b> HDMI, RJ-45, USB Type A connections.`

For this i am doing:

```
pattern=re.compile("(<b>(.*?)</b>)|(<strong>(.*?)</strong>)")
for label in labels:
    print(label)
    flag=0
    if(('Window'in label or 'Windows' in label) and ('<b>' in label or '<strong>' in label)):
        text=re.findall(pattern, label)
        print(text)
```

where labels is the list of such html elements containing tag. 
The output expected is `['Features Windows 10','including VGA,']`

Instead in a getting the outuput as: `[('', 'Features Windows 10 Pro'), ('including VGA,', '')]`

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't use regex to parse HTML. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2789863).

Comment: I'm confused. Why wouldn't your expected output include `pro`?

Answer (score 6):

Care for BeautifulSoup ?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = BeautifulSoup("""Customizable:<strong>Features Windows 10 Pro</strong> and legacy ports <b>including VGA,</b> HDMI, RJ-45, USB Type A connections""")

data.find_all('strong')[0].text
data.find_all('b')[0].text
```

Output

```
Features Windows 10 Pro
'including VGA,'
```

Answer (score 1):

First [you should not use regexes to parse markup text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3545273).

That being said, the result is *by design*. The documentation for `re.findall` is explicit about it (emphasize mine):

> re.findall(pattern, string, flags=0)
>
> Return all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string, as a list of strings. The string is scanned left-to-right, and matches are returned in the order found. If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of groups; **this will be a list of tuples if the pattern has more than one group**.

Your pattern contains 2 groups, one for `<b>`, one for `<strong>`. You get two tuples so that you can know what group was matched.

If you do not like that, you could use `finditer` instead which will return a match object. And `group(0)` on the match object is the part of the string that was matched:

```
text = [m.group() for m in pattern.finditer(label)]
```